# Is this how I combine two min-heaps together?

Tags: c++, heap

I am currently creating a source code to combine two heaps that satisfy the min heap property with the shape invariant of a complete binary tree. However, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the correct accepted method of merging two heaps satisfying the requirements I laid out.

Here is what I think:

Given two priority queues represented as min heaps, I insert the nodes of the second tree one by one into the first tree and fix the heap property. Then I continue this until all of the nodes in the second tree is in the first tree.

From what I see, this feels like a nlogn algorithm since I have to go through all the elements in the second tree and for every insert it takes about logn time because the height of a complete binary tree is at most logn.. But I think there is a faster way, however I'm not sure what other possible method there is.

I was thinking that I could just insert the entire tree in, but that break the shape invariant and order invariant..Is my method the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact building a heap is possible in linear time and standard function [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) guarantees linear time. The method is explained in Wikipedia article about [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap).

This means that you can simply merge heaps by calling `std::make_heap` on range containing elements from both heaps. This is asymptotically optimal if heaps are of similar size. There might be a way to exploit preexisting structure to reduce constant factor, but I find it not likely.